# Closed and Compact Subset of a Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, functions, metric-spaces, compactness

The following question is causing me some problems.

Consider the metric space $(X, d)$, where $X$ = $C([0, 1], \mathbb R)$ is the set of continuous functions

$f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$, and $d$ = $d_{\infty}$ is the distance which is given by

$$d(f,g)=\Vert f−g\Vert_{\infty}=\sup\{|f(t)−g(t)|:t\in[0,1]\}.$$

(a) $L=\{f\in X \mid \forall x,y\in [0,1] ,f(0) = 0,  \text{ and } ∀x, y ∈ [0, 1] : |f(y) − f(x)| \leq |y − x|^{1/4}\}$

i. Is $L$ closed?

ii. Is $L$ compact? Prove your answer

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also apologies for poor notation. I'm still new to the method of composing a question using this site. Thanks in advance

Comment: I considered using the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem for this question but I am unsure as to whether this would be the best method.

Comment: Why not prove that the limit of every converging sequence of functions in $L$ lies in $L$?

Comment: I understand your argument Lucas, could you perhaps inform me on the method in which you would use to show this. Also, following this proof would it be sufficient to state that as the metric space is itself compact that $L$ is also compact as it is a closed subset or would another proof be required?

Comment: The argument I was suggesting for proving the set is closed is essentially the same as the argument given by frafour. This metric space is in fact not compact, so no, you do need the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L$ is closed. First, notice that $L = L_0 \cap \bigcap\limits_{x, y \in [0, 1]} L_{x, y}$, where $L_0 = \{ f \in X :  f(0) = 0 \}$ and $L_{x, y} = \{ f \in X : |f(y) - f(x)| \leq |y - x|^{\frac{1}{4}} \}$. So it is enough to show that each of these sets is closed.

For $L_0$, pick $f \notin L_0$, so $f(0) = x \neq 0$. If $d(f, g) < |x|$, then $|g(0)| \geq |f(0)| - d(f, g) > 0$, so $g \notin L_0$.

For $L_{x, y}$, pick $f \notin L_{x, y}$, so $|f(y) - f(x)| - |y - x|^{\frac{1}{4}} =: \epsilon > 0$. If $d(f, g) < \epsilon / 2$, then $|g(y) - g(x)| - |y - x|^{\frac{1}{4}} \geq |f(y) - f(x)| - 2 d(f, g) - |y - x|^{\frac{1}{4}} > 0$, so $g \notin L_{x, y}$.

We conclude that $L$ is closed.

$L$ is compact. Recall the Arzela-Ascoli theorem: a subspace $Y \subset X$ is compact if and only if it is closed, uniformly bounded and equicontinuous. We already know that $L$ is closed. It is uniformly bounded, since for any $x \in [0, 1]$ we have $|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(0)| \leq |x - 0|^{\frac{1}{4}} \leq 1$. We are left to show equicontinuity.

Let $\epsilon > 0$, and $\delta := \epsilon^4$. Now let $x, y \in [0, 1]$ be such that $|y - x| < \delta$. Then $|f(y) - f(x)| \leq |y - x|^{\frac{1}{4}} < \delta^{\frac{1}{4}} = \epsilon$ for any $f \in X$.

We conclude that $L$ is compact.

Comment: you are a legend! Thank you so much

Comment: @GavinK14 since you are a new user, maybe I should remind you to accept my answer :)

Comment: Quick question, if i defined a $J$ = {$f$  ∈ $X$ | $f$(x) = 0 if 0 ≤ $x$ ≤ 1/2}, $J$ in this case would not be compact

Comment: @GavinK14 no: it would be closed but not compact: for instance it is not uniformly bounded because $f(1)$ can be arbitrarily large

Comment: I was expecting that result. Thank you. Is it sufficient to just state this or would you recommend I provide a proof similar to the one you stated above showing in this case that it is not uniformly bounded.

Comment: Well it depends from the context. But a sentence like "because it is not uniformly bounded" should be enough